# creating bitstring from numpy array in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, binary

I'm trying to create an integer from a numpy array of 1s and 0s, and I need to do it fast as I'll be doing up to 400 million of these.

```
x = numpy.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
y = integer representation of x
```

The numpy array could be created type string, ie

```
x=numpy.array(['1', '0', '1', '0', '0'])
```

I've haven't found anything yet that doesn't involve concatenations and type conversions before running

```
int(bits_as_string, 2)
```

which seems a lot of overhead.

I'm constructing an NK landscape for use with an evolutionary biology project. I have an N bit string with K of those bits interacting, and I'm generating 2^N performance values for every possible bit combination after jumping through a lot of other hoops to attach various weights to differing interactions. That's why I'm using binary digits. I'm currently using x as a list to which I'm appending the 1s and 0s. I'm trying to change this so that x is a numpy array and I simply change x[i] instead of appending to a list. I do believe the numpy array formulation will be faster than the string concatenation, but as I can't get it to work yet I haven't been able to benchmark ; )

Comment: What do you intend to do with the integers? You may have posed an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The integers serve as indexes for another numpy.array.

Comment: Why are you using binary digits? If you could explain the problem you're trying to solve with this code, we might be able to better help you.

Comment: See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil. Your assumption that the conversion is expensive is unwarranted.

Comment: gentlemen, see edits above.

Comment: How about `x.astype('S1')`?

Comment: Thankd @Divakar, I get output such as array([b'1', b'0', b'1', b'0', b'0'], 
dtype='|S1'), when what I want is '10100' or even better 20 as an integer.

Comment: How about `(2**(x.size - 1 - np.where(x)[0])).sum()` then?

Comment: @Divakar That gets me what I want at a cost of 4.69 microseconds. Thanks, I can go benchmark now, then figure out what you did!

Comment: It sounds like you want [`np.packbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html), although I agree with @msw that this is probably premature optimization.

Comment: @Dikaver, i've tried lots of combinations of your approach and you've described the fastest.

Comment: I'm not sure what's up with this premature optimisation criticism, my model is finished and I need to speed it up or figure out a rewrite. And the -2 reputation points?

Comment: @zazizoma Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build y at the same time you are building x?
That is, when the code does `x.append(bit)`, it also does `y = 2*y + bit`.

Comment: Hi @RootTwo, that's actually what I'm doing. I used to have all the xs in a matrix and ran a numpy.dot with z to get y but ran out of swap memory at over 4 billion elements. Now I'm trying to calculate y by x-rows numpy.dot z, but it's taking way too long (ie days). I'm attempting to optimize the loop, but may have to break the big x matrix into blocks. Thanks for your input!